# In flutter: the necessary "required" keyword when extracting a widget

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I'm working on an app and in the begin I extracted a widget to make my code clean and organized..

When I give the constracter the parameters, it force me to add "required" keyword, which it wasn't necessary befor!!

How can I ignore it?

```
class NewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  NewWidget({this.text, this.onPress});
  final String text;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        elevation: 5.0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        child: TextButton(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 100.0),
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 32.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: onPress(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the notification I had for it..

> The parameter 'text' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.  Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.

Comment: please share your code so we can take a look at it

Comment: I have shared it

Comment: Yes, now named parameter should include required in null safety version of dart. But if you want it be optional use `final String? text`;

Comment: Exactly, I want it to be optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes from Dart's nullsafety, your two parameters are defined as non-nullable variables but they are optional inside of your constructor which means the compiler cannot infer if the type should be `String` or `String?` for your `text` variable and cannot determine if `onPress` is a `Function` or `Function?`.

You either need to pass your parameters as `required` or declare them as nullable and check if they are `null` or not. Here is a sample for both cases:

**Adding required**

```dart
class NewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  NewWidget({required this.text, required this.onPress});
  final String text;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        elevation: 5.0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        child: TextButton(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 100.0),
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 32.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: onPress,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Using nullable parameters**

```dart
class NewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  NewWidget({this.text, this.onPress});
  final String? text;
  final Function? onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        elevation: 5.0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        child: TextButton(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 100.0),
            child: Text(
              text ?? "text String is null",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 32.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () => onPress!(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That was useful but some thing else faced me..
The function that I added in "onPress" parameter is navigator, but whent I added it it didn't go to distination page !!!